# JMS Message tracking across clusters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms

I have JMS implementation based on JBoss (to be precise, JBossMQ on JBoss4.2). There are 5 clusters, with each cluster having few nodes. One node in each of the cluster acts as master node. Out of the 5 clusters, one of the cluster is supposed to publish messages to a persistent Topic, and the other 4 clusters consumes those messages. The publishing and consuming is done by only the master node of each cluster.

I want to device a mechanism where the publisher knows that the message was consumed by all the subscribers or a subscriber knows that it has consumed all the messages produced by the publisher. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you use a JMS system in order to not care about that and only configure it the way you need. You could save state information in a shared resource like a database, but I wouldn't do it. Better use monitor features of the JMS system in order to track that. In case your application really needs to know about the successful processing of a message, then you could have a queue where process acknowledge go back to the sender.

For HornetQ, which you might use with JBoss, you'll find an example of a [clustered topic here](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/#d0e1891).

Comment: Should have mentioned that I am using JBoss 4.2 (I know it is outdated, but that is not under my control) which uses JBossMQ, so the HornetQ approach you suggested may not be helpful here